# what is this complex expression meaning?

Tags: php, zen-cart

code1 is a code from zencart core php file, I am confused what it is.
is code1 equal to code2 ? 
and what is the & ~ meanning ?

```
<?php 
/* code1 */
$errors_to_log = (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, 5.3, '>=') ? E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE : version_compare(PHP_VERSION, 5.4, '>=') ? E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT : E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

/* code2 */
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION,5.3,'>=')){
    $errors_to_log = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED &~E_NOTICE;
}else if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, 5.4, '>=')){
    $errors_to_log = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT;
}else{
    $errors_to_log = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
}
?>
```

Comment: usually in php, `&` refers to `BITWISE AND` operator and `~` refers to `BITWISE NOT` operator (bit inversion)...

Comment: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is code 1 equal to code 2?**

Yes. Code 1 uses nested `ternary operator` while code 2 uses the `else-if` structure. Code 1 would've been more clear if parentheses were used to show the precedence.

**What do `&` and `~` mean?**

`&` in php refers to BITWISE AND [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php). `~` in php refers to BITWISE NOT or Complement [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php). In this case, it gives the complement values of the constants.

However, you need to know that `~` has the highest precedence here.